# Manipulating bootstrap tabs, removing and adding tabs with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

Im kind of new to this. I would like to add and remove buttons from a tab, however i can't do it properly. It seems fairly simple but i wont work with the new buttons created using javascript. Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">


    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="..." id="dynagregarmarca">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class='btn-group' role='group'>
            <button type='button' id='following' class='btn btn-default' href='#tab3' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' aria-hidden='true'></span>
                <div class='hidden-xs'>Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content" id="tabcontent">

        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='tab-pane fade in' id='tab3'>
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>


</div>



<input type="button" id="btnagregarmarcatab" value="Add tab" />

<input type="button" id="btneliminarmarcatab" value="remove Selected tab" />


<script>





$(document).on("click", ".btn-pref .btn", function () {

        $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
        $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");  

});


$(document).on("click", "#btnagregarmarcatab", function () {


    var menu_html = "<div class='btn-group' role='group'>" + 
                            "<button type='button' id='followings' class='btn btn-default' href='#tab3' data-toggle='tab'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user' aria-hidden='true'></span>" + 
                            "<div class='hidden-xs'>Following</div>" + 
                            "</button>" + 
                    "</div>";

    var content = "<div class='tab-pane fade in' id='tab3'>" + 
                        "<h3>This is tab 3</h3>" + 
                    "</div>";


    $("#dynagregarmarca").append(menu_html);
    $("#tabcontent").append(content);
    
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");



});


$(document).on("click", "#btneliminarmarcatab", function () {


    let elementoprimary = $(".btn-primary");

    $(elementoprimary).parent().remove();



});


</script>
```

It only works removing the default buttons, but it removes everything if I try to remove the created buttons. Please I need some help or advice. Thanks a lot in advance. I need to do it the simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what parent should be removed. So instead of

```
$(elementoprimary).parent().remove();
```

you should use

```
elementoprimary.closest(".btn-group").remove();
```

You also should use `closest` instead of `parent`, because `closest` is much safer if your DOM layout changes.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I'll check out it

Comment: WOW my friends seems at first glance to be working great!! Thanks a lot my buddy, I need this for my work and my boss is kinda mad since ive trying to do this for a week. Thanks